# CsvFile.InferColumnTypes not available for FSharp.Data 2.2.3?

Tags: f#, f#-data

The following code works when using F#.Data 2.2.2.

```
let data = CsvFile.Load(fn)
let dt = data.InferColumnTypes(10000, [|""|], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "", false, true)
```

Now it stop working when using F#.Data 2.2.3. I checked the source file on GitHub https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/7caa9ed507dc0c69abc39ed438acb5af81080abd/src/Csv/CsvInference.fs and the source file is not changed since Oct 22, 2014. Why it suddenly stops working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `InferColumnTypes` method is an extension method, so you can only call it if you open the module where it is defined. The following works for me with the latest build of F# Data:

```
open FSharp.Data
open FSharp.Data.Runtime.CsvInference // <- This brings InferColumnTypes into the scope!

let fn = "C:\\some\\file.csv"
let data = CsvFile.Load(fn)
let ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
let dt = data.InferColumnTypes(10000, [|""|], ci, "", false, true)
```